Export files to Excel XLSX file using C# and ClosedXML.Excel
I have a problem with exporting my data to Excel XLSX format using C# ASP.Net and ClosedXML.Excel
In practice when I execute the stored procedure "sProc_20241009" on the MySQL DB I have this output

Instead when I export my data to Excel XLSX format using ClosedXML.Excel I get this output

Instead of the data present in the MySQL table there are numbers
My c# code below
    public static void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
    {
        string AppLocation = @"D:\inetpub\wwwroot\PUBLIC\ExcelFiles\";
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper().Replace("-", "_");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["guid"].Value = guid.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["guid"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);

        string filepath = AppLocation + "Export_" +
            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + "_" +
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["guid"].Value + ".xlsx";

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[i], ds.Tables[i].TableName);
            }
            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            wb.SaveAs(filepath);
            wb.Dispose();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " +
            "filename=Export_" +
            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + "_" +
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["guid"].Value + ".xlsx");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(@"D:\inetpub\wwwroot\PUBLIC\ExcelFiles\Export_" +
            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + "_" +
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["guid"].Value + ".xlsx");

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ExcelDownloadFlag")
        {
            Value = "Flag",
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }


       protected void btnxlsx_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
       {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (MySqlConnection con =
                new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                    new MySqlCommand("sProc_20241009", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 2147483;
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id.Text.ToString());

                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    ExportDataSetToExcel(ds);
                }
            }
        }

And this is the stored procedure "sProc_20241009" on MySQL DB
SELECT
    col1,
    col2 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        '_Date_Hour' col1,
        _Date_Hour AS col2 
    FROM
        check_list 
    WHERE
        _ID = @ID UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '_ID' AS _ID,
        _ID 
    FROM
        check_list
    WHERE
        _ID = @ID UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '_Area' AS _Area,
        _Area 
    FROM
        check_list 
    WHERE
        _ID = @ID   ) src;


What's the raw data in ds.Tables[i] when you run the code in the backend?

@Shadow The DataSet filled by MySQL is empty...

Then how can it produce any output?

@Shadow but why do I see the right result in the sproc?

Because that's correct.

@Shadow On the DataSet filled by MySQL I see only the values of "col1" from sProc, I don't have the values of "col2"
